# Differential equations notations confusion

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

Given these differential equations:

$\frac{d^2x}{dt^2} = 2\Omega\frac{dy}{dt}\sin(\lambda) - \frac{g}{L}x$

$\frac{d^2y}{dt^2} = -2\Omega\frac{dx}{dt}\sin(\lambda) - \frac{g}{L}y$

Now making the following substitutions:

$\frac{dx}{dt} = u$ and $\frac{dy}{dt} = v$ we have the following differential equations

$\frac{du}{dt} = 2\Omega v\sin(\lambda) - \frac{g}{L}x$

$\frac{dv}{dt} = -2\Omega u\sin(\lambda) - \frac{g}{L}y$

Now here is where I get confused, note that we can write $\frac{du}{dt} = f(t,u)$ and likewise for the other equation. But if that is so, then what would be my unknown variable for the first equation? Or is it wrong to write $\frac{du}{dt} = f(t,u)$?

Comment: Perhaps you mean $\frac{du}{dt} = f(t,v)$ since there doesn't seem to be any $u$ dependence in the equation for $\frac{du}{dt}$.  Or maybe there's some a priori reason to assume $u'$ depends on $u$?  Are you quoting this from somewhere?

Comment: Yes, I think you are right. I think it is more appropriate to write $\frac{du}{dt} = f(t,v,x)$

Comment: What is your goal?  I don't see the substitution in terms of the new functions $u$ and $v$ helping to determine what $x$ and $y$ are.

Comment: It is a first step in solving differential equations of order 2. We must first convert them  into a differential equation of order 1 so that it is easier to solve the differential equation

Comment: I am solving the above differential equations by numerical solution, that is, by using Runge-Kutta method

Comment: @user61835: Was my answer useful for you? :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think if you write the system as follows, it gets simpler, although it takes time.

$$D^2x=aDy-bx, ~~~\frac{dx}{dt}=Dx\\ D^2y=-aDx-by,~~~\frac{dy}{dt}=Dy$$ wherein $a=2\Omega\sin(\lambda), b=\frac{g}{L}$. So we get: $$(D^2+b)x-aDy=0\\\\ (D^2+b)y+aDx=0$$ By any method you know for solving abbove system, one gets: $$[(D^2+b)^2+a^2D^2]y=0$$ and $$[(D^2+b)^2+a^2D^2]x=0$$ Each of the above can converetd to standard form as, for example for $y(t)$, : $$[(D^2+b)^2+a^2D^2]y=0\to y^{(4)}+(2b+a^2)y''+b^2y=0$$ which  can be solved easily.

Comment: $\quad + 1 \quad$ :^D